# Angular 2-4 SETUP not able to run on windows

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to Angular 2/4, it was working fine before I  just followed the command at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli. I am running Angular 2-4 on my machine. But after some windows update I am no longer able to run Angular. it keep saying

I ran the following command and went through other command in github anugular CLI installation

```
>npm install -g @angular/cli or sometimes I ran npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install
ng serve
```

When I ran npm install -g @angular/cli . this the message below got.

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"
x64"})
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.13 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.46 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.10.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:267:18
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at moveAway (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:38:5)
npm ERR!     at destStatted (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\action\finalize.js:27:7)
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:267:18
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli' -> 'C:\Users\kislam\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\@angular\.cli.DELETE'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kislam\Documents\Angular\dynamicform-jan72017\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

After that I ran :

npm install
ng serve

I also followed the steps here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

nothing seem to work

**ERROR** I am getting error when i ran `ng serve`

[image]

```
C:\Temp\angular\dynamicformjan72017>ng serve
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have included screen grab of the node-module permission.
[image]
Can someone help ? I am running window 7 professional

Comment: How did your ">npm install -g @angular/cli" ended? Were there any errors?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem lack of description is too generic...try to give us your angular cli version and the exact steps you try to do...

Comment: Which version of node you are running on? `node -v`. Seems like your install is not successful. It could also be caused by your bin directory got moved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your globally installed `@angular/cli` package is not working correctly.

You should try uninstalling/reinstalling it or changing the folder options (read only). Usually, the `EPERM` error is caused because of read / write permissions on windows.

This link will help you do it correctly : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I changed from C drive to  Documents folder. it still didn't work

Comment: It's not about moving them, it's about the folder rights. Check if the folder `npm` containing the `node_modules` is not in `read-only`

Comment: thanks I will try that and Whats the reason for not recognizing ng serve .. ..ng serve
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I have posted screen grab .angular still  doesn't recognize ng serve

Comment: I guess that is because you moved the folder... It has to do with the windows CMD and the PATH variables. Since you moved the folder, most probably the PATH linked to the windows CMD is not working anymore. You should really cleanup all of this and reinstall angular/cli globally.

Comment: I didnt move..I jsut switched directory and installed angular their using npm install.  i just ran it in the new Document folder instead of the C/project folder